# How to override TestNG pass or fail result

Tags: java, testng

- I am using TestNG to run data driven tests
- My data is read from an external file
- I have a retry logic that is essentially a different test method in the same class but retries only the failed entities from the previous test. I am controlling that using priority

  ```
  Test(dataProvider="customTestDataProvider" , priority = 1)  
  public void testSomething(final ITestContext testContext , final CustomTestDataItem testData) throws CustomTestException{       
      setTestData(testData, testContext);
      performStep1();
      performStep2();
      validateResult();
  }

  @Test(dataProvider="customTestDataProvider" , priority = 2) 
  public void testSomethingRetry1(final ITestContext testContext ,final CustomTestDataItem testData) throws CustomTestException{
      testSomething(testContext , testData);
  }

  @Test(dataProvider="customTestDataProvider" , priority = 3) 
  public void testSomethingRetry2(final ITestContext testContext ,final CustomTestDataItem testData) throws CustomTestException{
      testSomething(testContext , testData);
  }
  ```
- customTestDataProvider knows which testData item the method has failed for so in `testSomethingRetry1` only the failed test data will be supplied
- If a test method fails in `testSomething` it is retried in `testSomethingRetry1` but testNG considers it is failed since it failed in `testSomething`
- So I need a custom logic to determine if the suite has passed or failed. How do i override the testNG result( pass/fail) with the result I have determined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of duplicating test methods I would recommend to use `org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer` which basically runs failed test again. You can see some example here http://seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/execute-only-failed-test-cases-using-iretryanalyzer.

But if you really want to override result you can use listeners and implement methods in which you get `ITestResult`. In this object you can check method class/name/result/etc. and change some of these attributes (including result).

http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestListener.html
http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener.html

or for whole test suite

http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ISuiteListener.html

Comment: So the retry logic works but the test is still marked as failed

Comment: Yes, but it depends on what's your expected behavior e.g. if there will be 3 runs of one test a two of them fails and one is successful, in test context will be all these runs. So you can implement some additional logic in `org.testng.TestListenerAdapter#onTestSuccess / org.testng.TestListenerAdapter#onTestFailure / etc.` or after all tests in `org.testng.ISuiteListener#onFinish` which handles behavior you want.